# Why should I use SpinWait?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, locking

I have written two `lock-free update` helper methods inspired by [Joseph Albahari](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx#_SpinLock_and_SpinWait) & [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5087722/1226568)

Looking at the 2nd implementation why would I need the `SpinWait` in the 1st implementation? What are the advantables/disadvantages of one over the other?

Please note this question is not about what `SpinWait` does but rather specific to how these two methods differ in execution.

```
public static void LockFreeUpdate1<T>(ref T field, Func<T, T> updater) where T : class
{
    var spinner = new SpinWait();

    T snapshot;    
    while (true)
    {
        snapshot = field;

        if (snapshot.Equals(
               Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref field, updater(snapshot), snapshot))) { return; }

        spinner.SpinOnce();
    }
}


public static void LockFreeUpdate2<T>(ref T field, Func<T, T> updater) where T : class
{
    T snapshot;
    do
    {
        snapshot = field;                

    } while(
        snapshot.Equals(
           Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref field, updater(snapshot), snapshot)));
}
```

Comment: Note that due to CPU caching, the `snapshot = field;` might not notice changes to the field - if you *expect* it to, you should use `Volatile.Read`. The only reason for a spin-wait here is that if you're *actively competing* (and losing) with another thread: you might as well give it a picosecond to finish what it is doing. Note that `updater` could be called multiple times, which may be unexpected

Comment: Tnx Marc, `Interlocked.CompareExchange` generates a memory barrier so we will just end up with an extra loop iteration if stale value is read, no?